# Is something divided by something equals 0 or 1?

Tags: trigonometry

$\cos(x) (\sin(x) + 1) = sin(x) (1 + sin(x))$

I can set the ones in the bracket $= 0$ and get the first $x$.
But in the solutions of the teacher there is

$\cos(x) = sin(x) \Rightarrow  1 = sin(x) / cos(x)$

Where does that $1$ come from? Wouldn't it be $0$?

Comment: What is $\frac{\cos(x)}{\cos(x)}$?

Comment: $a=b$ where $a,b\neq 0$ implies $a/b=b/b=1$

Comment: What do you mean @Arthur?

Comment: It comes from your equality $\cos(x)=\sin(x)$ when you divide both sides by $\sin(x)$. On the right hand side, you get $\sin(x)/\sin(x)$ which equals 1.

Comment: This is why you should be careful before cancelling. As a heuristic, always transpose all terms to one side  before cancelling. In you case, you have:$$\cos x(1 + \sin x) = \sin x(1+\sin x)$$ . Take the right hand side to the left, and you get: $$  (\cos x - \sin x)(1+\sin  x) = 0$$. Now, you are within rights to cancel, "as long as none of the terms on the left are zero". When are they zero? One's when $\sin x  + 1 = 0$, and that you have pointed out. The other, is $\cos x - \sin x = 0$, which your teacher has pointed out.

Comment: "I can set the ones in the bracket = 0": either I minsunderstand the meaning or no, setting factors to $0$ just makes the equation vanish. "Where does that 1 come from? Wouldn't it be 0?": no, you are dividing by $\cos x$.

Answer (score 4):

Algebraically speaking, the situation is the following: 
$$b(1+a)=a(1+a).$$
which, by bringing the term on the right to the left, can be rewritten as
$$(b-a)(1+a)=0.$$
As a product of factors is zero iff at least one of the factors is zero we get a solution either if 
$$1+a=0\iff a=-1\iff \sin(x)=-1\iff x\in-\pi/2+2\pi k, \ k\in \mathbb Z$$
or 
$$b-a=0\iff b=a\iff \cos(x)=\sin(x)\iff x=\pi/4+\pi k, \ k\in \mathbb Z.$$